# Show updated records SQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a script that updates records in a customer table.

Is there an elegant way to run an update and simply print what was updated rather than running another `SELECT` with the same `WHERE CONDITION` functionality.

The only way I know how to do it is to do a select first, then update each record in the select, and then print it out.

That is:

```
if(isset($dry_run)) {
    SELECT a, b, c, d FROM customer
}
else {
    UPDATE CUSTOMER set d='blah'
}
```

It would be nice if `UPDATE` could return a result set that I could then print out to show customer_id, firstname, lastname and email of all the updated records without writing code and without hitting the Database more than once. Does something like that exist?

-- Edit --

Since the consensus is **No, can't be done** - Can anyone explain why SQL cannot bundle the updated rows up into an object that you can then iterate over and print out?

Comment: The short answer: no. The long answer: `UPDATE` doesn't return a result set. You'll need to do a `SELECT`.

Comment: Darn :( its strange they cannot do a `SELECT FOR UPDATE` or something similar :(

Comment: `select for update` is for locking the fields in a transaction, if you only want to do a dry run, you don't need that

Comment: Yea I realise that, - its just a shame they can't put the newly updated rows into a cursor to then iterate over and print out.

Comment: @FaddishWorm I think you would find that functionality to have limited applicability, as it can basically already be done with selects. If you really want that functionality with a single call, you might seek to build his out with a stored procedure.

Comment: Mmm, thats true... I think there would be MANY applications if you could ask SQL for what changed after an update. So much code is written just to print a report of what changed when you write the batching type scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need an update? You should be able to do a select for this.  For example, say you were going to update a record where customer_id is some value. You could just run a select for the row(s) with that value.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain properly... I want to show what was updated without having to re-run my "dryrun" code/queries

Comment: @FaddishWorm you still would need a select query.  You should be able to use the same where conditions (unless the update changed values on one of the condition fields).

Comment: yea, I have a select query... thats not the points though... I want to dump what changed after my update with 1 query

Comment: @FaddishWorm I guess that where I don't follow you.  You know EXACTLY what just changed as you set both the conditions and the values for the update.

Comment: Not necessarily, because the where  could be a wildcard search e.g. `UPDATE * WHERE email like "% %"` -- need to print the customer_ids affected

Comment: @FaddishWorm you still have the search value available to you do you not? SELECT customer_id WHERE email LIKE '%search term%'. ThAt gives you all customer I'd values that would have been touched by your update.

Comment: Yea, I understand that, sorry I updated my question to be a bit more clearer... I think the answer is just "no" by the sounds of it and I have to do a SELECT with the same WHERE CONDITIONAL as the UPDATE to print what changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a select instead of your update

Instead of doing

```
UPDATE table set column1=value1, column2=value2 WHERE conditions
```

you can do

```
SELECT value1 as column1, value2 as column2 FROM table WHERE conditions
```

which will give you the same results.

Comment: Lol, yes I am aware of UPDATE and SELECT statements, thanks... Maybe I didn't explain properly... I want to show what was updated without having to re-run my "dryrun" code/queries

Comment: Ok, so, `update` does not return values, it updates the values in your database. What I meant is, you can just run the `select` in place of your `update`, and you'll get the values that would be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the code.

```
if(!isset($dry_run)) {
    UPDATE CUSTOMER set d='blah'
}
SELECT a, b, c, d FROM customer
```

---

And to answer your question. The update and select operation are different. No need to read the whole record to update them.

If you do want, write a MySQL procedure that executes both update and select.

If you wonder why it can't do like in other languages where you have a cursor to read and write, the answer is that's slower.

Comment: missing the point again. maybe shouldn't have mentioned the dry-run bit

Answer (score 0):

If you have got data from your client for update , why you will need the data to be fetched again after update query. you already have that data in your request get it echoed.